# C++ name mangling in a so

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking, shared-libraries, name-mangling

Here's what i did:

I changed a .h file from

```
SomeObj* getCacheObj( int i = 0 );
```

to

```
SomeObj* getCacheObj( int i );
SomeObj* getCacheObj();
```

I recompiled the code (no problems), the changes went to somelib.so (one of **many** so files). I then replaced the old so on the equipment with this one and got the folowing error when loading the so: 
`undefined symbol: _ZN13KeypathHelper11getCacheObjEv`

Now the strange part is that I've been told this class is only used in this so file (How can I make sure?). I am not that experienced and not sure how to investigate. Any suggestions are welcome.

**Update**

This particular problem was caused because another so file was using the KeypathHelper class and I only replaced the one containing it. The way I found out which other so needed to be updated was by greping all so's for KeypathHelper.

Comment: Was changing the .h all you did? no changes in the .cpp files?

Comment: i did add a implementation for the the new method of course

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `_ZN13KeypathHelper11getCacheObjEv` symbol is a mangled name for `KeypathHelper::getCacheObj()` (you can easily translate using [`c++filt`](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/binutils/c_002b_002bfilt.html), for example). Given that you have only added a method and whatever is loading the shared object cannot find it makes me think that you either haven't updated the shared object or forgot to provide a definition for `KeypathHelper::getCacheObj()` (in other words — implement the method).

In order to investigate, you have to see what is failing to resolve the symbol. Usually, developers have a sense for it.  Say, if a binary `XXX` cannot load library `YYY` due to unresolved symbol, then `XXX` is using it and it does not appear to be in `YYY` (or anywhere else for that matter).  If there is no sense for that, one can resort to reading [ld.so (8) manual page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ld.so%208) and debug the dynamic linker by using available means like defining `LD_DEBUG`.

Also, @PlasmaHH has asked a very good question. If the only change you made was to the header file, then you must know that a single function/method with a default value for a parameter is not the same as as two functions/methods where one has a parameter and one does not.

As for your second question about how to make sure that symbol in a shared object is not being used outside — you have to change the symbol visibility so that nobody from the outside is able to link/resolve/use the symbol. For example, see [GCC Visibility](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility).

Hope it helps. Good Luck!